# How would i transfer a select option value to a button using onclick with php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a quiz app utilizing CI. I have 2 buttons on the homepage to choose between take a quiz that is 'not graded' and just picks random questions, allowing the user to exit without a grade at any point. The second choice is to take a graded quiz and by selecting the number of questions you want the quiz to be, and as a result outputs a graded score at the end.

Right now the graded questions option is a button that leads to nothing with a select option underneath.  It currently takes you to the quiz onchange of the select option.  I am trying to have it allow the user to select the the number of questions, and then have them click the button, sending that select option value to the window.location onclick.

```
<a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" id="choose_quiz_type">Take a Graded Quiz</button>
<select id="homepagequizcount" onchange="window.location= '<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url')."index.php/question?gra=1&qnum="; ?>'+this.value" name="">

    <option value="0">-Questions-</option>                
    <?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < count($count); $i++)
    echo '<option value="'.($i+1).'">'.($i+1).'</option>';
    ?>

</select>
```

How would I configure this?

Comment: YOu need to use a client side script for that (most likely javascript), so you might want to retag your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment that you might be looking for javascript (as I gather from your title), but if you want a purely php and html solution (which I gather from the tags and body):

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url')."index.php/question"; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="gra" value="1">
    <select id="homepagequizcount" name="qnum">
    <option value="0">-Questions-</option>                
    <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($count); $i++)
            echo '<option value="'.($i+1).'">'.($i+1).'</option>';
    ?>              
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" id="choose_quiz_type">Take a Graded Quiz</button>
</form>
```

To use a number input instead of a select, replace the select with

```
<input type="number" name="qnum" />
```

Comment: how would this work if i wanted the input type to be number instead of select?

Comment: @Fuscon Replace the select with the input in my edited answer.